# Python - Split nth occurence of a character in string

Tags: python

I needed this function for a project I'm currently working on. I think there is definitely a way to make this prettier and have tickle more performance out of it, but how?

```py
def nthofchar(string: str, char: str, n: int = 2) -> list:
    l = []  # New list
    temp = ""  # temp value
    count = 0  # Counter, that get will be reset, each time the temp get`s appended to the list

    for value in string.split(char):
        temp += value + char  # Add char to have it still in the string

        # Incrementing
        count += 1
        if count >= n:
            l.append(temp[:len(char) * -1])  # Remove last char
            # Reset
            count = 0
            temp = ""

    return l



print(nthofchar("25:hellwdasd:64:da:12:yeah:1:y", ":", 2))
# Output: ['25:hellwdasd', '64:da', '12:yeah', '1:y']

print(nthofchar("1;a;2;b;3;c;4;d;5;e;6;f", ";", 2))
# Output: ['1;a', '2;b', '3;c', '4;d', '5;e', '6;f']
```

Answer (score 6):

A python idiom for iterating over a sequence in groups it to use `zip()` like so:

```
group_iter = zip(*[iter(seq)]*n)
```

where `seq` is the sequence and `n` is the size of each group. Note that the last group will be dropped if it doesn't have `n` elements.

Using that idiom, your function could be coded:

```
def nthofchar(string: str, char: str, n: int = 2) -> list:
    chunks = string.split(char)
    groups = zip(*[iter(chunks)]*n)

    return [char.join(group) for group in groups]
```

Added a test case for n != 2:

```
print(nthofchar("1;a;b;2;c;d;3;e;f;4;g;h;5;i;j;6;k;l", ";", 3))
# Output: ['1;a;b', '2;c;d', '3;e;f', '4;g;h', '5;i;j', '6;k;l']
```

Comment: This fails for `n != 2`, because then the tuple unpacking in your return line does not work anymore.

Comment: @Graipher, fixed

Comment: Now the last sentence is not true anymore, but otherwise, nice!

Answer (score 4):

You can simply take advantage from builtin [`range(start, stop[, step])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) and collect the needed chunks passing input `n` size as *range*'s `step` parameter:

```
def split_nth(inp_str: str, sep: str, n: int = 2) -> list:
    chunks = inp_str.split(sep)
    return [sep.join(chunks[i: i + n]) for i in range(0, len(chunks), n)]


print(split_nth("25:hellwdasd:64:da:12:yeah:1:y", ":", 3))
```

The output:

```
['25:hellwdasd:64', 'da:12:yeah', '1:y']
```